# smarty math tag rounding

Tags: math, smarty

I have the following smarty tag:

```
 {math equation=1.1+0.7 format="%.0f"}
```

Which outputs 2 (rounding up). Can this be rewritten to always round down like floor() does in php.
And please I DO NOT have access to the php source or the smarty configuration to do this in a more appropriate fashion.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

```
     {math equation=1.1+0.7 format="%.2f"}
```

Try that.

Comment: So you want it to round down to 1?

Comment: {math equation=1.1+0.7|floor format="%.0f"} is what you need, tested it myself works perfectly. Now if you want it to show two decimal places you can do this instead {math equation=1.1+0.7|floor format="%0.2f"}

Answer (score 2):

{math equation="floor(1.1+0.7)" }

This works for me